# how get values of StringArray in String?

Tags: java, android, arrays

i have a arraylist and put parameters in StringArray and then i split the StringArray values to a String but my code is so dirty! can anyone suggest me how can i do this better?

```
    String name = null, color = null, num = null;

    String[] nameArray = new String[cartArrayList.size()];
    String[] colorArray = new String[cartArrayList.size()];
    String[] numArray = new String[cartArrayList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < cartArrayList.size(); i++) {
        nameArray[i] = cartArrayList.get(i).getName();
        colorArray[i] = cartArrayList.get(i).getColor();
        numArray[i] = cartArrayList.get(i).getNumber();
    }

    for (String NAME : nameArray) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    for (String COLOR : colorArray) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), COLOR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    for (String NUM : numArray) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), NUM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: You mean: `How to convert an ArrayList to three String arrays?`

Comment: Does your Cart Object have only these fixed attributes or more?

Comment: @blackapps i already have three String Array but i use three `for` to show them split and i want show them in a `for`...

Comment: I feel you can directly use cartArrayList.get(i).getName()  by looping over list.

Comment: @ParagGoel no i want store them in a row in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String name = null, color = null, num = null;



for (Cart cart : cartArrayList) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), cart.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), cart.getNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), cart.getColor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

Comment: Why three toasts? `for (Cart cart : cartArrayList) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), cart.getName() + "\n" + cart.getNumber() + "\n" + cart.getColor(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}`

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can use the Stream API and particularly the map function:

```
String[] nameArray = cartArrayList.stream().map(cart -> cart.getName()).toArray(String[]::new);
 String[] colorArray = cartArrayList.stream().map(cart -> cart. getColor()).toArray(String[]::new);
 String[] numArray = cartArrayList.stream().map(cart -> cart. getNumber()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: that's right I edit the answer to be clear